# How to continue WaterfallStep instead of calling Dispatcher

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have created a chatbot that uses a LUIS model an a Qna-Maker model, and i took https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot and 
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/14.nlp-with-dispatch as examples.

Now I ended up with a bot, using a dispatcher in the ActivityHandler. When the dispatcher returns the general LUIS intent, I start a Dialog and call the LuisRecognizer to get a strongly typed result.

But my problem is: When I started a WaterfallDialog that uses a Prompt, the answer from the user also gets evaluated by the dispatcher and it might end up calling the QnA-Maker, which is wrong.
How can I make sure the bot only calls the dispatcher after my WaterfallDialog is finished?

I do not know the actual dialog-stack in the ActivityHandler

Comment: To clarify; you do not want the prompt response to be evaluated _at all_ against the dispatcher, only after that dialog has completed?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Because the user gets asked to type any text as a description. And that text might be falsely assigned to QnA maker. I guess I have to store something in UserState or ConversationState, to evaluate one of them in my activityhandler at the beginning of the turn. But I did not get it working yet